# Qt Regex matches HTML Tag InnerText

Tags: html, regex, qt

I have a html file with one `<pre>...</pre>` tag. What regex is necessary to match all content within the pre's?

```
QString pattern = "<pre>(.*)</pre>";
QRegExp rx(pattern);
rx.setCaseSensitivity(cs);

int pos = 0;
QStringList list;
while ((pos = rx.indexIn(clipBoardData, pos)) != -1) {
  list << rx.cap(1);
  pos += rx.matchedLength();
}
```

list.count() is always 0

Answer (score 3):

HTML is not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), you do not use regular expressions to parse it.

Instead, use [QXmlSimpleReader](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qxmlsimplereader.html) to load the XML, then [QXmlQuery](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qxmlquery.html) to find the PRE node and then extract its contents.

Comment: <html>
     <body>
      <pre>some text to excerpt</pre>
     </body>
    </html>

for such a simple file? maybe its simpler to substring the content...

Comment: I don't agree. If you know file structure well then finding content in it shouldn't be a problem with regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

## [DO *NOT* PARSE HTML USING Regular Expressions!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Instead, use a real HTML parser, such as [this one](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qdomdocument.html)

Comment: I don't agree. If you know file structure well then finding content in it shouldn't be a problem with regular expression.

Comment: @PredragManojlovic: What if the file structure changes slightly? What if there are escaped characters?

Comment: I was quite precise: "If you know file structure well". Meaning, you have generated it, or system which is generating it is consistent.

Comment: @PredragManojlovic: That leads to very brittle code which is difficult to change (or makes changes result in subtle bugs).

Comment: With all due respect, that is a nonsense

Answer (score 0):

i did it using substrings:

```
int begin = clipBoardData.indexOf("<pre");
int end = clipBoardData.indexOf("</body>");

QString result = data.mid(begin, end-begin);
```

The result includes the `<pre's>` but i found out thats even better ;)

Answer (score -1):

I have to agree with the others. Drupal 6.x and older are using regex to do a lot of work on the HTML data. It quickly breaks if you create pages of 64Kb or more. So using a DOM or just `indexOf()` as you've done is a better much faster solution.

Now, for those interested in knowing more about regex, Qt uses the perl implementation. This means you can use the lazy operator. Your regex would become:

```
(<pre>.*?</pre>)+
```

to get each one of the <pre> block in your code (although if you have only one, then the question mark and the plus are not required.) Note that no delimiters at the start and end of the regular expression are required here.

```
QRegExp re("(<pre>.*?</pre>)+", Qt::CaseInsensitive);
re.indexIn(html_input);
QStringList list = re.capturedTexts();
```

Now list should have one <pre> tag or more.

Comment: Just a note "?" is not a greedy operator. It is a non-greedy modifier.

Comment: Which is why I used "*?".

Comment: Yes but it ws stated as: "This means you can use the greedy operator" instead of This means you can use the non-greedy modifier"

Comment: @PredragManojlovic Ah! Ooop! Fixed my answer with the correct term.